# Manipulation delta reporting large ( wrong) values which causes infinite rotation

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was trying to rotate Some stackPanel around Y Axis by using the e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X of event ManiuplationDelta,
Then the rotation was going weird when the stackPanel.Projection.rotationY is near 90 degree. after debugging I found that e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X value was sometimes -2000 or 3000 etc..

Why is it reporting such a large ( wrong ) numbers. Any Help?

Check below for the snippet of code.

Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Background="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >
<StackPanel x:Name="Under" Background="DarkCyan" ManipulationDelta="ContentPanel_ManipulationDelta" >
            <TextBlock Text="Under" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="48"/>
            <StackPanel.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationX="0.5" CenterOfRotationY="0.5" RotationY="0"/>
            </StackPanel.Projection>

    </Grid>
```

C#

```
  private void ContentPanel_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ;
        double FullWidth = (sender as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth;
        delta = e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X;
        if (Math.Abs(delta) > FullWidth)
        {
            //Something wrong
            Debug.WriteLine("Cumulative x: " + e.CumulativeManipulation.Translation.X);
            Debug.WriteLine("width: " + (sender as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth);
            Debug.WriteLine("");
        }
        double RotateValue = (delta / FullWidth) * -180;
        var Underprojection = (Under.Projection as PlaneProjection);
        Underprojection.RotationY = RotateValue;
    }
```

**Edit:
I found the problem , I didn't set CenterOfRotationZ to the value "0.5"**